# How to align two divs horizontally (and the text above it) despite doing float and display

Tags: html, css

I wanted to align these 2 `<a>` tags horizontally with a margin between them but then they overlapped on each other. I think it's because of `position: absolute` but if i were to use `position: relative` it would be a mess and i want the text above it to move too if i were to zoom in on the page. How do I do that?

```css
.loginsebagai h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  color: #333333;
  top: 28%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loginsebagaimurid {
  width: 220px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}

.loginsebagaimurid-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 175px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #ffa603;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 175px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.loginsebagaimurid-top i {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  /* aligning */
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  /* aligning */
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #c97a01;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.loginsebagaimurid:hover i {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 125px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.loginsebagaimurid-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
}

.loginsebagaimurid-bottom h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: black;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.loginsebagaimurid:hover h3 {
  background-color: #eb6810;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
}


/* loginsebagai.php admin */

.loginsebagaiadmin {
  width: 220px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}

.loginsebagaiadmin-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 175px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #ffa603;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 175px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.loginsebagaiadmin-top i {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  /* aligning */
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  /* aligning */
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #c97a01;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.loginsebagaiadmin:hover i {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 125px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.loginsebagaiadmin-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
}

.loginsebagaiadmin-bottom h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: black;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.loginsebagaiadmin:hover h3 {
  background-color: #eb6810;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginsebagai">
  <h2>Log Masuk sebagai...</h2>
  <a href="index.php" class="loginsebagaimurid">
    <div class="loginsebagaimurid-top"><i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="loginsebagaimurid-bottom">
      <h3>Murid</h3>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="indexadmin.php" class="loginsebagaiadmin">
    <div class="loginsebagaiadmin-top"><i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="loginsebagaiadmin-bottom">
      <h3>Murid</h3>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly. The relevant code belongs directly into your question, in text form and properly formatted, and not just dumped onto an external platform.

Answer (score 0):

add this at last of your css and check if you wanted the same

```css
.loginsebagai a {

      display: flex;
      width:100%;
      justify-content: space-between;

}
```